# XCode 4.5 downloading documentation

Tags: macos, xcode, documentation

I have installed XCode 4.5. During the installation there was an error about downloading the documentation. I did not pay much attention, but I think the error was same as that mentioned in: 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683380/xcode-4-5-some-install-error).

I tried the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12684100) as mentioned in the post, but there is no file named as: "**com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleOSX10_8.CoreReference.docset**" as stated in the answer.

The main problem I have with the documentation is that it is incomplete. **While some of the pages are displayed properly, the other pages are blank.**

How do I repair the documentation? I am ready to re-download the documentation. I do NOT want to download the entire XCode 4.5 again. Please help!!!

**Note:** I am using Mountain Lion 10.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that directly form Xcode preferences:

1. Open Xcode
2. Menu *Xcode* > *Preferences*
3. Go to the tab *Download*
4. Go to the sub-tab *Documentation*
5. Select the documentation you want to re-install
6. Click the <kbd>-</kbd> icon below the documentations list for moving it to the trash.
7. Click install on the desired documentation

Maybe you can skip the step 6 if Xcode shows that the documentation is not installed.

Comment: Wow, the documentation files are really large. I guess I will just look into tutorials from youtube for now. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Robik Did it work? If you are interested in iOS programming there is a wonderful course on iTunes U. It comes frome the university of Stanford. It is called "iPad and iPhone application development"

Comment: 1. I did not download the docs because they were too large and internet speed here is too slow. I will to it afterwards. In fact, my internet stops working whenever I pause or turn off the MacOSX in VMware. I think I need to start another thread for that. 2. About the videos: We downloaded videos from youtube. (BUT THEY WERE FROM 2010 and a lot has changed!), so I am now installing iTunes in windows and surfing about how to download iTunes videos (because streaming is really not an option in my case). I will add more comments afterwards.

Comment: I found this link (inside itunes): https://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255# . Are these videos the latest? and are these lectures compliant with XCode 4.5?

Comment: Also, videos are being downloaded too slowly. I googled, but could come up with a way to download less size/ low quality videos instead. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Robik These are the videos. However you should open a new question, otherwise no one will be able to find this question by using the search functionality and the information will help only you! ;-)

Comment: Yes. I asked about the internet connection problem here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68981/download-videos-faster and about video download here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68981/download-videos-faster.

Comment: Sorry, the link about internet connection problem is this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68945/computer-should-be-restarted-to-connect-internet-mountain-lion-on-vmware-8