# Computer should be restarted to connect internet (Mountain Lion on VMware 8)

Tags: macos, virtualization, internet, router

I have **Mountain Lion 10.8** on **VMware 8**.
I am using **auto-bridging (vmnet0)** for internet service.
The internet works find until I pause or turn off the virtual machine. When I resume or restart it, the internet connection does not work. I pinged localhost, but there was no response.

When I restart the **host (Windows 7)**, then the internet connection inside guest OS (Mac) works fine again.

My laptop is connected to a switch, which is further connected to a router via ethernet. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Mac OS X is only supported as guest OS when the host OS is OS X - and then it only OS X Server that VMware allow the install of.

Therefore I think you are missing some necessary driveres.

Comment: But why does the internet work after restarting then? Is there a way to save that "state" or configuration?

Comment: I don't know what the problem could be ?? Have you installed the VMware Tools on your OS X guest ?

Comment: No. I will install them now.

Comment: I installed them from darwin.iso. But the problem still persists.